# Minesweeper At Work

Tags: code-golf, random, minesweeper

Everyone knows the old minesweeper game that shipped with Windows XP. It's a simple grid with a 9x9 matrix of cells containing either a number (indicating how many mines are adjacent to it) or a mine.

[image]

The challenge is to generate a random 9x9 grid with 10 bombs given any integer seed (up to whatever your machine/language's largest int is) with brownie points if you implement the PRNG yourself

example output: cells contain either numerals 0-8 or * for mines

```
*101*1000
110111000
123210000
1***10000
123210011
00000002*
00000114*
000112*3*
0001*2121
```

Shortest code in bytes wins.. standard rules etc, etc..

Comment: You should indicate what the numbers mean :)

Comment: Microsoft Minesweeper is a heck of a lot [older than XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Minesweeper) and minesweeper-like games date back to at least the 60s.

Comment: Also, I don't have time to play Minesweeper while at work -- I'm too busy on PPCG. ;-)

Comment: What counts as a PRNG, exactly? How many different configurations must it be able to produce? Can we _not_ use the seed and just generate a different configuration each time, if our language has a PRNG which is _automatically_ initallized to a "random" seed?

Comment: @TimmyD But XP's version is the first version that had a 9x9 grid. Anything older uses an 8x8 grid for Beginner. #outnerded ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Dyalog APL, 40 bytes

[`⎕rl←1⋄(1,¨a)⍕¨{⍉3+/0,⍵,0}⍣2⊢a←9 9⍴9≥?⍨81`](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395io%u21900%u22C4%20%u2395rl%u21901%u22C4%281%2C%A8a%29%u2355%A8%7B%u23493+/0%2C%u2375%2C0%7D%u23632%u22A2a%u21909%209%u23749%u2265%3F%u236881&run)

(assumes `⎕io←0`)

the `1` in `⎕rl←1` is the seed

from right to left:

`?⍨81` is the same as `81?81` - a random permutation

`9≥` results in a bitmask containing ten 1s at random positions, the rest are 0s

`a←9 9⍴` reshape to a 9-by-9 square and call it "a"

`{ }⍣2` do the following twice:

`⍉3+/0,⍵,0` sliding window sum of 3 columns (assume 0s outside), then transpose

`(1,¨a)⍕¨` is format (convert to string) each. The left argument to `⍕` specifies the total number of characters and fractional characters in the result. If `⍕` can't format according to that spec it outputs a `*` - a lucky coincidence for this problem. `a` will be 1 where the mines are - trying to fit a whole and fractional part into a single char is impossible, so those will appear as `*`s.

Comment: Can you explain the `⎕io←0` assumption? I'm not familiar with Dyalog APL...

Comment: Array indices in Dyalog are 1-based by default. Setting `⎕io` (the "[Index Origin](http://help.dyalog.com/15.0/Content/Language/System%20Functions/io.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=%E2%8E%95IO)") to 0 makes them 0-based and changes some primitives accordingly, e.g.
`⍳3` will be `0 1 2`, not `1 2 3`.
That can be done either programmatically (`⎕io←0`) or from the preferences in the GUI.
Having this choice is a 50-year-old mistake that still splits the tiny APL community of today.

Answer (score 5):

## MATLAB, <s>94</s> 93 bytes

```
rng(input(''));x(9,9)=~1;x(randperm(81,10))=1;y=[conv2(+x,ones(3),'s')+48 ''];y(x)=42;disp(y)
```

Example run (the first line after the code is the input typed by the user):

```
>> rng(input(''));x(9,9)=~1;x(randperm(81,10))=1;y=[conv2(+x,ones(3),'s')+48 ''];y(x)=42;disp(y)
99
*10001*2*
220001232
*201111*1
*312*1111
12*211000
011211000
0001*1000
000112110
000001*10
```

#### Explanation

```
rng(input(''));
```

takes an integer and uses it as seed. (This works in modern MATLAB versions. Old versions may need a different syntax.)

```
x(9,9)=~1;
```

assigns logical `0`, or `false` (obtained by logically negating `1`) to the entry `(9,9)` of a matrix `x`. The rest of the entries are automatically initiallized to logical `0` too.

```
x(randperm(81,10))=1;
```

assigns `1` (autoomatically cast to logical `1`, or `true`) to `10` of the 
`81` entries of `x`, chosen randomly without replacement. These entries are the ones that contain bombs.

```
conv2(+x,ones(3),'s')
```

is an abbreviation of `conv2(+x,ones(3),'same')`. It convolves the matrix `x` (which needs to be cast to `double`, using `+`) with a 3×3 neighbourhood containing `1`. This counts how many bombs are adjacent to each entry. For entries that contain a bomb it includes that bomb, but the value there will be overwritten later.

```
y=[...+48 ''];
```

adds 48 to the value, to convert from number to ASCII code. Concatenating with the empty matrix casts these ASCII codes to chars.

```
y(x)=42;
```

assigns 42 (ASCII code for `'*'`) to the positions of the bombs. These positions are given by `x`, which is here used as a logical index.

```
disp(y)
```

displays the result.

Answer (score 4):

### Javascript (ES6), 204 or 198 bytes

#### Custom PRNG (204 bytes)

```
s=>(p=-1,S=n=>(x=p%9-(n+=p)%9)*x-64&&b[n]=='*',T=n=>S(n)+S(-n),b=[...'*00000000'.repeat(9)]).sort(_=>(s=(22695477*s+1)>>>0)&1||-1).map(c=>(p++,c=='0'?T(1)+T(8)+T(9)+T(10):c)).join``.match(/.{9}/g).join`
`
```

This code is using a linear congruential generator with multiplier `22695477` and increment `1` (this is the Borland C/C++ implementation).

Due to the poor efficiency of the PRNG during its warmup phase, I had to place one bomb per row (instead of 10 at the beginning or 10 at the end of the unshuffled array). So, there are only 9 bombs. I may try to fix that later.

Also, there must be a simpler/shorter way of processing the 'out of board' check `(x=p%9-(n+=p)%9)*x-64` but I just can't figure it out right now.

#### Using Math.random() (198 bytes)

```
s=>(p=-1,S=n=>(x=p%9-(n+=p)%9)*x-64&&b[n]=='*',T=n=>S(n)+S(-n),b=[...'**********'+'0'.repeat(71)]).sort(_=>Math.random()-.5).map(c=>(p++,c=='0'?T(1)+T(8)+T(9)+T(10):c)).join``.match(/.{9}/g).join`
`
```

This one includes 10 mines as requested.

#### Demo

```js
let f =
_=>(p=-1,S=n=>(x=p%9-(n+=p)%9)*x-64&&b[n]=='*',T=n=>S(n)+S(-n),b=[...'**********'+'0'.repeat(71)]).sort(_=>Math.random()-.5).map(c=>(p++,c=='0'?T(1)+T(8)+T(9)+T(10):c)).join``.match(/.{9}/g).join`
`
console.log(f())
```

Comment: `'**********'+'0'` is equal to `'**********'+0`; that saves two bytes on the 198-byte-version.

Comment: @PaulSchmitz - Unfortunately this `'0'` is supposed to be repeated and `0.repeat()` wouldn't work.

Comment: Oops, I though it would get executed like `...('**********'+0).repeat(71)`. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

## R, 187 Bytes

```
set.seed();x=1:121;y=x[!(x%%11 %in% 0:1|(x-1)%/%11 %in% c(0,10))];z=sample(y,10);x=x*0;for(t in z){p=t+c(-10:-12,-1,1,10:12);x[p]=x[p]+1};x[z]=9;m=data.frame(matrix(x[y],9));m[m==9]='*';m
```

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/zymTCe)

Explanation:

`set.seed()` take a cst seed.

`x` is the index for a 11*11 matrix

`y` is the index of the 9*9 matrix in the 11*11 matrix

`z` is the index of the bomb

`x=x*0` initialise the matrix value

The loop add 1 to x in case of adjacent bomb.

Comment: I think you have to take the argument to set.seed() as input.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>269</s> <s>266</s> 264 bytes

```py
from random import*
seed(input())
z=1,0,-1
n=range(9)
m=[[0]*9 for _ in n]
for x,y in sample([[x,y]for x in n for y in n],10):
 m[x][y]=-9
 for a in z:
  for b in z:
    if 0<=x+a<9>0<=y+b<9:m[x+a][y+b]+=1 # it gets displayed as 4 spaces, but the beginning of this line is a single tab
print("\n".join("".join([`c`,'*'][c<0]for c in l)for l in m))
```

[Try it on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/d71T7h)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Aaron.

Most likely still golfable.

#### Explanation

`random` is imported for using `seed` to seed the PRNG and `sample` to select ten bomb locations randomly. `m` is a 9 x 9 matrix saving the board. For each of the bomb locations, the corresponding entry in `m` gets set to `-9` and all neighbouring entries get incremented. This way `m` ends up containing the count of adjacent bombs for non-bomb cells and a negative number for bomb cells. The final `print` prints the whole board by iterating through all lines `l` in `m` and all cells `c` in `l`.

Comment: What exactly is 'random' used for, exactly?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp probably to seed the random number generator indirectly used by `sample()`

Comment: save 2 bytes by mixing tab indents inside `for a in z:` block (only python 2.x)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript ES6, 244 bytes

```js
f=(a=[...Array(11)].map(_=>Array(11).fill(0)),n=10,r=_=>Math.random()*9|0,x=r(),y=r())=>a[x+1][y+1]>8||[0,1,2].map(i=>[0,1,2].map(j=>a[x+i][y+j]++),a[x+1][y+1]=9)&&--n?f(a,n):a.slice(1,-1).map(a=>a.slice(1,-1).map(n=>n<9?n:`*`).join``).join`
`
;o.textContent=f()
```

```html
<pre id=o>
```

Comment: You may want to elaborate on which part is your code.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere The first 244 bytes, hopefully ;-) The first line should be 242 bytes long, then there's the newline and the `\`` character.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>181</s> <s>194</s> 183+1 = 184 bytes

Forgot to actually set the seed, whoops. Uses the `-n` flag.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#LcrdCoIwGADQ@z2FUUEpfm6Z4arlg4jEWoGL/GEr2nB7dqPs@pz5TL0uNojbUSveXhdneHZniTgrcRXmBJUhBshxBZo3/eO2IngNDe8HJ92bySU91Ewm9MBLWbGYUrRSLCYA5L@MMxF7I3PEzplTXuC9msA6G7Ea2S/YH/CShjYyVcSI9x71r6cO@JSFE0dcFOFeeLh3sgUteBskMFCfjGNKtiSjm12WZh8)

```ruby
srand$_.to_i
a=[0]*81
[*0..80].sample(10).map{|i|w=i%9;h=i/9;a[i]=-99
(r=-1..1).map{|x|x+=w
x<0||x>8?0:r.map{|y|y+=h
y<0||y>8?0:a[9*y+x]+=1}}}
puts a.map{|c|c<0??*:c}.join.scan /.{9}/
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 172 bytes

```python
from random import*
seed(input())
r=range
b=set(sample(r(81),10))
for j in r(9):print''.join([[`len({x-10,x-9,x-8,x-1,x+1,x+8,x+9,x+10}&b)`,'*'][x in b]for x in r(j,81,9)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzRCoMgGEbvewqv5m/ZyNhFDnqSCCqyzSiVPweOsWd3xi4O3wcHjnv7pzV1jAvaneBo5jR6dxZ9nh1KzaCNe3lgLMM26YfKpvZQHo5xd5sChEYwLqrkF4tkJdoQBMnuDrXxlF5Xqw103bApA59QioqHUiaahOChOEm/kOevvpeJDZzmtO/CmZr6sxr@1ZU3gkvWsxhv9Q8)